# Horizontally centering all children of a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to horizontally center all children of a `RelativeLayout` that is vertically centered towards its parent. My initial gut feeling was to toy with the gravity of the `RelativeLayout`, but that just centers the layout towards its parent. Playing with the gravity of the child views triggers other undesired behavior.

Here's what happens when I adjust the gravity of the `RelativeLayout`:

[image: Example]

Desired behavior is that the `TextView` moves a little bit to the right so that it's horizontally centered relative to the screen. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Can you please add some more detail? Like xml of your layout?

Comment: Try set android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" for all chidren od relativelayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this property to your `TextView` should work:

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example :

```
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Output :
[image]

Comment: Your solution came in just a few minutes after the answer I accepted, but your suggestion of adding `android_layoutCenterInParent="true"` to every child element worked for me as well. Thanks!